# Why can't I unmount any volumes using finder anymore?

Tags: macos, finder

I have not been able to unmount any volumes from Finder on my mac since several 10.6.x upgrades ago. Has anyone else experienced this problem? I can umount them from any other sources (Disk Utility, etc) or the terminal (umount /Volumes/xxx), but absolutely never from the Finder.

Mac OS X 10.6.4 intel macbook

Comment: What happens when you drag a volume to the trash?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Console.app open and see if it has anything related to say.

Comment: Which log should I be looking at specifically?

Comment: @jessica "All Messages" might be a start.

Answer (score 0):

As far as troubleshooting is concerned, the absolute lowest place to start would be from a new user account with no login items. Create one in System Preferences, and try unmounting immediately after login. It could be something in your user account that's causing the problem. Usually when I have a similar issue, I might quit all open applications and relaunch the Finder (option-right click the icon in the Dock) to make sure nothing is using the volume's resources.